# Winform Trackbar value in one form not passing to second form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 winforms and I would like to pass data between them.

Form 1 is nothing more than a large picturebox.

Form2 stays open all of the time on top of form 1.  It acts as a semi-transparent control with an Exit button and I added a trackbar.  The Exit button works just fine, however I'm having trouble reading the value of the trackbar if the value changes.

What I would like to happen is if the value of the trackbar changes, it sends the value to the first form and triggers an event.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Form1 is

```
    public sbyte value
    {
        get { return Exitform.myValue; }
    }

    public Fullscreenpreview(string filename)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += this.pictureBox_MouseMove;

        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(filename);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();

        //to show exit button which is a seperate form
        var frm3 = new Exitform();
        frm3.FormClosed += (o, e) => this.Close();

        frm3.Show();
        frm3.TopMost = true;
        //to show exit button which is a seperate form

        if (myValue != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("zoinks the value is = " + value);
        }
    }
```

form 2 is

```
public partial class Exitform : Form
{
    private const int CpNocloseButton = 0x200;

    private bool mouseIsDown = false;
    private Point firstPoint;

    public static sbyte myValue = 0;

    public Exitform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TopMost = false;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
            myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CpNocloseButton;
            return myCp;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        firstPoint = e.Location;
        mouseIsDown = true;
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441762/how-can-i-move-windows-when-mouse-down
    }

    private void label1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseIsDown = false;
    }

    private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseIsDown)
        {
            // Get the difference between the two points
            int xDiff = firstPoint.X - e.Location.X;
            int yDiff = firstPoint.Y - e.Location.Y;

            // Set the new point
            int x = this.Location.X - xDiff;
            int y = this.Location.Y - yDiff;
            this.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }

    private void contrast_trackbar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myValue = 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the Trackbar Scroll event the same way how you are binding to the Close event. You just need to prepare a "connection" between the Form1 and Form2.

1. Create a public property (e.g. int TrackBarValue) in the Form2 which returns the actual value of the TrackBar.
2. Create a public custom event (e.g. EventHandler TrackBarValueChanged) in the Form2 which will be fired when the TrackBar value changes
3. Bind to the TrackBarValueChanged event from the Form1

If it is still not clear, let me know in a comment.

Form1.h

```
public Fullscreenpreview(string filename)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += this.pictureBox_MouseMove;

    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(filename);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();

    //to show exit button which is a seperate form
    frm3 = new Exitform();
    frm3.FormClosed += (o, e) => this.Close();
    frm3.OnTrackBarValueChanged += new EventHandler(TrackBarValueChanged_Event);

    frm3.Show();
    frm3.TopMost = true;
    //to show exit button which is a seperate form
}


private void TrackBarValueChanged_Event(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ExitForm exit = (ExitForm)sender;
     MessageBox.Show("zoinks the value is = " + exit.TrackBarValue.ToString()); 
}
```

Form2.h

```
public partial class Exitform : Form
{
    private const int CpNocloseButton = 0x200;

    private bool mouseIsDown = false;
    private Point firstPoint;

    public event EventHandler OnTrackBarValueChanged;

    public Exitform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TopMost = false;
    }

    public int TrackBarValue
    {
        get
        {
            return contrast_trackbar.Value;
        }
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
            myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CpNocloseButton;
            return myCp;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        firstPoint = e.Location;
        mouseIsDown = true;
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441762/how-can-i-move-windows-when-mouse-down
    }

    private void label1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseIsDown = false;
    }

    private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseIsDown)
        {
            // Get the difference between the two points
            int xDiff = firstPoint.X - e.Location.X;
            int yDiff = firstPoint.Y - e.Location.Y;

            // Set the new point
            int x = this.Location.X - xDiff;
            int y = this.Location.Y - yDiff;
            this.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }

    private void contrast_trackbar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnTrackBarValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it was driving me bananas.  I was trying so many combinations, I started to lose track of what I was doing and started causing even more problems.  With your tip and another blog I found, I had a slightly different solution, but your help got me in the right mindset and took me to the solution.  I will post the code I ended up using later.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Zoltan and an answer provided in stackoverflow 
[Zoom using two forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537782/zoom-using-two-forms) . Provided me with the answer I was looking for.  The Zoom using two forms I did not find immediately from the title.

The only reason I am posting this as an answer, is to show the new code as a separate entry below Zoltan answer rather than having to scroll down below my code to see his reply.

The variable names have changed from the first posting as I was just experimenting.

form 1

```
public sbyte contrast
{
    get { return Exitform.contrastvalue; }
}

public Fullscreenpreview(string filename)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += this.pictureBox_MouseMove;

    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(filename);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();

    //to show exit button which is a separate form
    var frm3 = new Exitform();
    frm3.FormClosed += (o, e) => this.Close();
    frm3.TrackBarMoved += new Action<int>(ChangeContrast);//<< Added

    frm3.Show();
    frm3.TopMost = true;
    //to show exit button which is a separate form

    frm3.FormClosed -= (o, e) => this.Close();//<< for memory leaks
    frm3.TrackBarMoved -= new Action<int>(ChangeContrast);//<< for memory leaks
}

private void ChangeContrast(int contrastVal)
{
    MessageBox.Show("zoinks the value is = " + contrastVal);
}
```

form 2

```
public partial class Exitform : Form
{
    private const int CpNocloseButton = 0x200;

    private bool mouseIsDown = false;
    private Point firstPoint;

    public static sbyte contrastvalue = 0;

    public Exitform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TopMost = false;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
            myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CpNocloseButton;
            return myCp;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        firstPoint = e.Location;
        mouseIsDown = true;
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441762/how-can-i-move-windows-when-mouse-down
    }

    private void label1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseIsDown = false;
    }

    private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseIsDown)
        {
            // Get the difference between the two points
            int xDiff = firstPoint.X - e.Location.X;
            int yDiff = firstPoint.Y - e.Location.Y;

            // Set the new point
            int x = this.Location.X - xDiff;
            int y = this.Location.Y - yDiff;
            this.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }

    public event Action<int> TrackBarMoved;// << public event to sense if the trackbar is moved
    private void contrast_trackbar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sbyte contrastVal = (sbyte)(this.contrast_trackbar.Value);//local variable just for use in trackbar

        TrackBarMoved(contrast_trackbar.Value);//pull value is trackbar moved

        string trackerbarvalue = Convert.ToString(contrastVal, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);// convert to string to push to label
        contrastlabel.Text = trackerbarvalue;//actual push to label

        contrastvalue = (sbyte)contrast_trackbar.Value;
    }
}
```

There are only a few small changes to the code other than some renaming of variables, internal cleanup, and a reporting to a label the value of the trackbar.  As Zoltan correctly pointed out I needed to bind the trackbar scroll event the same way I was binding the close event.  This is done with.

```
frm3.TrackBarMoved += new Action<int>(ChangeContrast);//<< Added
```

I also added an unsubscribe to help against resource leaks

```
frm3.FormClosed -= (o, e) => this.Close();//<< for memory leaks
frm3.TrackBarMoved -= new Action<int>(ChangeContrast);//<< for memory leaks
```

In the other form

```
public event Action<int> TrackBarMoved;// << public event to sense if the trackbar is moved
```

is used to broadcast the event

Thanks
Andy